# Duplicate entry in an exist DB

Tags: exist-db

I have an exist-db version 2.2 under Windows 7, Java "1.7.0_65".  I want to make a server-side backup.

When starting the server side backup (zipped) I am getting at the console the following Exception:

`Loading mime table from file C:\ProgramData\eXist-db\mime-types.xml
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: db/____lost_and_found__/_contents.xml
        at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.putNextEntry(Unknown Source)
        at org.exist.backup.ZipWriter.closeContents(ZipWriter.java:63)
      ...`

My question is how I can delete this duplicate entry. In fact I don't care deleting all stuff from lost_and_found if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about `lost and found` you could delete the `db/____lost_and_found__` before performing the backup. It does sound like a bug though.

If that works, could you open an issue on the eXist GitHub bug tracker please?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No, unfortunately deleting the content of __lost_and_found__ didn't help. Any other suggestion?